# Ubuntu LXD iptables SNAT / Masquarade

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, lxc, lxd

i have Ubuntu Server with LXD.
Every Container has own IP (local)address.
Example: LXD Host: 10.10.1.200, DNS container: 10.10.1.141, LXC inside address: 10.71.85.107

Ok - that no problem, incoming packages are translate:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.10.1.141 -i ens160 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.71.85.107:53
```

and in iptables i have:

```
254K   18M DNAT       udp  --  ens160 *       0.0.0.0/0            10.10.1.141          udp dpt:53 to:10.71.85.107:53
```

work fine.

**Problem is with outgoing package:**
I need that outgoing packages from container have the same IP address.
The same example:
DNS container: outgoing packages should have address 10.10.1.141
So add to iptables this:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.71.85.107 ! -d 10.71.85.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.1.141
```

and in iptables i have this:

```
 166K   13M SNAT       all  --  *      *       10.71.85.107        !10.71.85.0/24        to:10.10.1.141


330 27582 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       10.71.85.0/24       !10.71.85.0/24        /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
```

works fine!

**Real problem is when i restart LXD host**, then i have this in iptables:

```
    330 27582 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       10.71.85.0/24       !10.71.85.0/24        /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
     166K   13M SNAT       all  --  *      *       10.71.85.107        !10.71.85.0/24        to:10.10.1.141
```

**Masquerade is on the TOP!** and all outgoing package have LXD Host address (10.10.1.200)
Is any chance to change this? Why LXD always set Masquerade first? Is any chance to change this?

Answer (score 0):

That's a 2 months old question but as no one gave an answer and google often leads people to any of the Stack* sites, why not giving one.

I am going to focus on the question in the OP. I am completely ignoring the mentioned setup.

> Why LXD always set Masquerade first? Is any chance to change this?

Yes, LXC allows you to at least somehow define where it is going to add its rules. Have a look at the Parameter Documentation of LXC-Networking : [LXC Network Parameters](https://lxd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/networks/)
The parameter `ip4.nat.order` defines whether to add lxc NAT rules **before** or **after** pre-existing network rules.

You can view networks known to lxc from a shell via `lxc network list`
Editing a network is done by the command `lxc network edit <network name>`

---

**Example:**

A standard lxc network would be `lxdbr0`
Therefore just do `lxc network edit lxdbr0` and add `ip4.nat.order: "after"` to the configuration.

```yaml
config:
  ipv4.address: 10.0.4.1/24
  ipv4.nat: "true"
  ipv4.nat.order: "after"
description: ""
name: lxdbr0
type: bridge
used by:
- /1.0/containers/c1
- /1.0/containers/c2
- /1.0/containers/c3
managed: true
status: Created
locations:
- none
```

> HINT: You can also keep lxc away from doing nat rules by setting ipv4.nat to `false`. You then need to do the masquerade rule yourself, but there may be use-cases benefiting from a setup like that.